# Advanced Excel sorting issue with multiple row conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I want Excel to sort data based on whether or not TWO fields have equal content. This might get complicated, but I'll try my best to explain. I've attached a screenshot of a small snippet of the spreadsheet with the categories.

[image: Here]

Basically I need it to sort depending on whether the following conditions are met within TWO ROWS:

"FAQ GUID" needs to have the same value on both rows
"Mapping 1" needs to contain the content "Classification one" and "Classification two" on the the rows respectively. 
"Conditions title" need to have the same two pieces of content, like "ID+V" after "Classification one" and "Escalation" after "Classification two". 
However, I need it to also sort those cases by grouping together the rest of the identical "FAQ GUID".

Basically I want Excel to bunch together FAQ GUID cases where the two classifications, Classification One and Classification Two, match up in their following "Condition Title" content, like all cases where ID+V and Escalation are both present as in the screenshot attached.

In case this sounds crazy or nonsensical, a bit of background story might help on what I'm trying to achieve, in case you have a some tips:

I need to group together 8 versions of all FAQs together, one for each language, and the only thing they have in common is that their classification one and classification two are the same. However, as I have 80.000 rows, this would take literally a month to do if I can't do it automatically.

Any help guys? My apologies if this seems messy, as you might have guessed I'm not the most Excel savvy guy but I learn fast so go nuts.

My own theories include:

Using functions to meet the three conditions.
Using color to eliminate one out of three conditions (coloring all Classification one rows green for example)

Comment: If I solve it, do I get the job at said major tech company?

Comment: I don't have time to delve into the problem fully, but is what you will want to do is create helper columns to test whether logic is met or not, and then sort on these. you can use 1 and 0 in place of true and false, and then sum the 1s etc. to create a proper hierarchical ranking system.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on the spec here - you need to sort, or filter? this sentence "cases where the two classifications, Classification One and Classification Two, match up in their following "Condition Title" content, like all cases where ID+V and Escalation are both present as in the screenshot attached." seems contradictory... etc.
Regardless, @PeterH has it right - for each condition as you understand it, create a helper column to test against that condition. If you run into any specific snags, post back. You should be able to step towards a solution that way.

Comment: @Alex-M Thanks guys. My issue is however that I am not good enough to create a function that will sort this out for me. You mention that I should use helper columns, but what exactly would these helper columns contain in order for me to properly sort this in the intended way? 

Regarding the contradictory sentence, all of the titles would be present as column categories in the screenshot. I've highlighted one of the cases with yellow in the picture that contains an example. I simply need to find duplicates of those conditions and then group them with the FAQ GUIDS

Comment: @James "what exactly would these helper columns contain" 
"whether the following conditions are met"...
'"FAQ GUID" needs to have the same value on both rows' = one column
'"Mapping 1" needs to contain the content "Classification one" and "Classification two" on the the rows respectively' = another column
etc.
Your problem is hard for us to figure out because you use words like 'sort', 'bunch', 'group together' interchangeably and it's not clear what outcome you're trying to achieve. So, we're trying to coach you to help yourself to a solution, step by step.

Comment: @Alex-M Thank you Alex,

"Sort" would be referring to the "Sorting" function.

The reason I use the words "Group together" and "bunch" is because I need to include all duplicates of the FAQ GUID's when sorting. I simply need them to be sorted to the top depending on whether or not the column "Conditions Title" contains the same cells outside of the row that contains  "Classification One" and "Classification Two", so in the example shown I would want all the ones that have "ID+V" AND "Escalation" to the top, but containing all duplicates of their FAQ GUID